# MYSQL tuning to optimize CPU usage

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds

I sometimes have a spike in CPU to 70% (usually 20%) and looking if there is anything I can do to improve. I am using mysql rds 5.6.44

I am using m4.large instance on aws

Variables and version https://pastebin.com/1b1WQTk3

Here are my settings

```
mysql> show global status;

| Aborted_clients                               | 4                   
| Aborted_connects                              | 1068                
| Binlog_cache_disk_use                         | 189                 
| Binlog_cache_use                              | 216687              
| Binlog_stmt_cache_disk_use                    | 0                   
| Binlog_stmt_cache_use                         | 58                  
| Bytes_received                                | 10392043028         
| Bytes_sent                                    | 298689136353        
| Com_admin_commands                            | 329463              
| Com_assign_to_keycache                        | 0                   
| Com_alter_db                                  | 0                   
| Com_alter_db_upgrade                          | 0                   
| Com_alter_event                               | 0                   
| Com_alter_function                            | 0                   
| Com_alter_procedure                           | 0                   
| Com_alter_server                              | 0                   
| Com_alter_table                               | 0                   
| Com_alter_tablespace                          | 0                   
| Com_alter_user                                | 0                   
| Com_analyze                                   | 0                   
| Com_begin                                     | 9635                
| Com_binlog                                    | 0                   
| Com_call_procedure                            | 0                   
| Com_change_db                                 | 91419               
| Com_change_master                             | 0                   
| Com_check                                     | 0                   
| Com_checksum                                  | 0                   
| Com_commit                                    | 9366                
| Com_create_db                                 | 0                   
| Com_create_event                              | 0                   
| Com_create_function                           | 0                   
| Com_create_index                              | 0                   
| Com_create_procedure                          | 0                   
| Com_create_server                             | 0                   
| Com_create_table                              | 0                   
| Com_create_trigger                            | 0                   
| Com_create_udf                                | 0                   
| Com_create_user                               | 0                   
| Com_create_view                               | 0                   
| Com_dealloc_sql                               | 0                   
| Com_delete                                    | 40905               
| Com_delete_multi                              | 24                  
| Com_do                                        | 0                   
| Com_drop_db                                   | 0                   
| Com_drop_event                                | 0                   
| Com_drop_function                             | 0                   
| Com_drop_index                                | 0                   
| Com_drop_procedure                            | 0                   
| Com_drop_server                               | 0                   
| Com_drop_table                                | 0                   
| Com_drop_trigger                              | 0                   
| Com_drop_user                                 | 0                   
| Com_drop_view                                 | 0                   
| Com_empty_query                               | 0                   
| Com_execute_sql                               | 0                   
| Com_flush                                     | 476                 
| Com_get_diagnostics                           | 0                   
| Com_grant                                     | 0                   
| Com_ha_close                                  | 0                   
| Com_ha_open                                   | 0                   
| Com_ha_read                                   | 0                   
| Com_help                                      | 0                   
| Com_insert                                    | 80355               
| Com_insert_select                             | 0                   
| Com_install_plugin                            | 0                   
| Com_kill                                      | 0                   
| Com_load                                      | 0                   
| Com_lock_tables                               | 0                   
| Com_optimize                                  | 0                   
| Com_preload_keys                              | 0                   
| Com_prepare_sql                               | 0                   
| Com_purge                                     | 0                   
| Com_purge_before_date                         | 427                 
| Com_release_savepoint                         | 0                   
| Com_rename_table                              | 0                   
| Com_rename_user                               | 0                   
| Com_repair                                    | 0                   
| Com_replace                                   | 21869               
| Com_replace_select                            | 3                   
| Com_reset                                     | 0                   
| Com_resignal                                  | 0                   
| Com_revoke                                    | 0                   
| Com_revoke_all                                | 0                   
| Com_rollback                                  | 2                   
| Com_rollback_to_savepoint                     | 0                   
| Com_savepoint                                 | 0                   
| Com_select                                    | 12146517            
| Com_set_option                                | 3210675             
| Com_signal                                    | 0                   
| Com_show_binlog_events                        | 0                   
| Com_show_binlogs                              | 1                   
| Com_show_charsets                             | 0                   
| Com_show_collations                           | 0                   
| Com_show_create_db                            | 0                   
| Com_show_create_event                         | 0                   
| Com_show_create_func                          | 0                   
| Com_show_create_proc                          | 0                   
| Com_show_create_table                         | 90174               
| Com_show_create_trigger                       | 0                   
| Com_show_databases                            | 4                   
| Com_show_engine_logs                          | 0                   
| Com_show_engine_mutex                         | 0                   
| Com_show_engine_status                        | 0                   
| Com_show_events                               | 0                   
| Com_show_errors                               | 0                   
| Com_show_fields                               | 90967               
| Com_show_function_code                        | 0                   
| Com_show_function_status                      | 740                 
| Com_show_grants                               | 1                   
| Com_show_keys                                 | 0                   
| Com_show_master_status                        | 60                  
| Com_show_open_tables                          | 0                   
| Com_show_plugins                              | 0                   
| Com_show_privileges                           | 0                   
| Com_show_procedure_code                       | 0                   
| Com_show_procedure_status                     | 740                 
| Com_show_processlist                          | 18217               
| Com_show_profile                              | 0                   
| Com_show_profiles                             | 0                   
| Com_show_relaylog_events                      | 0                   
| Com_show_slave_hosts                          | 0                   
| Com_show_slave_status                         | 2187                
| Com_show_status                               | 2544                
| Com_show_storage_engines                      | 0                   
| Com_show_table_status                         | 89942               
| Com_show_tables                               | 536996              
| Com_show_triggers                             | 89942               
| Com_show_variables                            | 72924               
| Com_show_warnings                             | 0                   
| Com_slave_start                               | 0                   
| Com_slave_stop                                | 0                   
| Com_stmt_close                                | 1                   
| Com_stmt_execute                              | 132208              
| Com_stmt_fetch                                | 1                   
| Com_stmt_prepare                              | 25                  
| Com_stmt_reprepare                            | 20                  
| Com_stmt_reset                                | 0                   
| Com_stmt_send_long_data                       | 0                   
| Com_truncate                                  | 78                  
| Com_uninstall_plugin                          | 0                   
| Com_unlock_tables                             | 712                 
| Com_update                                    | 170586              
| Com_update_multi                              | 0                   
| Com_xa_commit                                 | 0                   
| Com_xa_end                                    | 0                   
| Com_xa_prepare                                | 0                   
| Com_xa_recover                                | 0                   
| Com_xa_rollback                               | 0                   
| Com_xa_start                                  | 0                   
| Compression                                   | OFF                 
| Connection_errors_accept                      | 0                   
| Connection_errors_internal                    | 0                   
| Connection_errors_max_connections             | 0                   
| Connection_errors_peer_address                | 0                   
| Connection_errors_select                      | 0                   
| Connection_errors_tcpwrap                     | 0                   
| Connections                                   | 4450022             
| Created_tmp_disk_tables                       | 414618              
| Created_tmp_files                             | 6582                
| Created_tmp_tables                            | 3908039             
| Delayed_errors                                | 0                   
| Delayed_insert_threads                        | 0                   
| Delayed_writes                                | 0                   
| Flush_commands                                | 1                   
| Handler_commit                                | 12464012            
| Handler_delete                                | 16467               
| Handler_discover                              | 0                   
| Handler_external_lock                         | 33320128            
| Handler_mrr_init                              | 0                   
| Handler_prepare                               | 575726              
| Handler_read_first                            | 96176049            
| Handler_read_key                              | 435827791           
| Handler_read_last                             | 7963                
| Handler_read_next                             | 517813660           
| Handler_read_prev                             | 1679848             
| Handler_read_rnd                              | 25957740            
| Handler_read_rnd_next                         | 722327597           
| Handler_rollback                              | 3880                
| Handler_savepoint                             | 0                   
| Handler_savepoint_rollback                    | 0                   
| Handler_update                                | 1355412             
| Handler_write                                 | 122420271           
| Innodb_buffer_pool_dump_status                | not started         
| Innodb_buffer_pool_load_status                | Buffer pool(s) load 
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_data                 | 130272              
| Innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_data                 | 2134376448          
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_dirty                | 4                   
| Innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_dirty                | 65536               
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_flushed              | 868226              
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_free                 | 800                 
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_misc                 | 0                   
| Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_total                | 131072              
| Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead_rnd             | 0                   
| Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead                 | 1000051             
| Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead_evicted         | 56726               
| Innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests              | 2288688850          
| Innodb_buffer_pool_reads                      | 10633702            
| Innodb_buffer_pool_wait_free                  | 0                   
| Innodb_buffer_pool_write_requests             | 3262668             
| Innodb_data_fsyncs                            | 526541              
| Innodb_data_pending_fsyncs                    | 0                   
| Innodb_data_pending_reads                     | 0                   
| Innodb_data_pending_writes                    | 0                   
| Innodb_data_read                              | 191240474624        
| Innodb_data_reads                             | 11672411            
| Innodb_data_writes                            | 1275287             
| Innodb_data_written                           | 29277500416         
| Innodb_dblwr_pages_written                    | 868226              
| Innodb_dblwr_writes                           | 119388              
| Innodb_have_atomic_builtins                   | ON                  
| Innodb_log_waits                              | 0                   
| Innodb_log_write_requests                     | 1485837             
| Innodb_log_writes                             | 262034              
| Innodb_os_log_fsyncs                          | 286824              
| Innodb_os_log_pending_fsyncs                  | 0                   
| Innodb_os_log_pending_writes                  | 0                   
| Innodb_os_log_written                         | 814815744           
| Innodb_page_size                              | 16384               
| Innodb_pages_created                          | 18711               
| Innodb_pages_read                             | 11672394            
| Innodb_pages_written                          | 868226              
| Innodb_row_lock_current_waits                 | 0                   
| Innodb_row_lock_time                          | 194                 
| Innodb_row_lock_time_avg                      | 5                   
| Innodb_row_lock_time_max                      | 20                  
| Innodb_row_lock_waits                         | 36                  
| Innodb_rows_deleted                           | 16468               
| Innodb_rows_inserted                          | 78261               
| Innodb_rows_read                              | 1187774810          
| Innodb_rows_updated                           | 216800              
| Innodb_num_open_files                         | 11                  
| Innodb_truncated_status_writes                | 0                   
| Innodb_available_undo_logs                    | 128                 
| Key_blocks_not_flushed                        | 0                   
| Key_blocks_unused                             | 13396               
| Key_blocks_used                               | 370                 
| Key_read_requests                             | 47246510            
| Key_reads                                     | 162                 
| Key_write_requests                            | 17276565            
| Key_writes                                    | 0                   
| Last_query_cost                               | 0.000000            
| Last_query_partial_plans                      | 0                   
| Max_used_connections                          | 196                 
| Not_flushed_delayed_rows                      | 0                   
| Open_files                                    | 6                   
| Open_streams                                  | 0                   
| Open_table_definitions                        | 10000               
| Open_tables                                   | 10000               
| Opened_files                                  | 1951917             
| Opened_table_definitions                      | 104279              
| Opened_tables                                 | 503015              
| Performance_schema_accounts_lost              | 0                   
| Performance_schema_cond_classes_lost          | 0                   
| Performance_schema_cond_instances_lost        | 0                   
| Performance_schema_digest_lost                | 829187              
| Performance_schema_file_classes_lost          | 0                   
| Performance_schema_file_handles_lost          | 0                   
| Performance_schema_file_instances_lost        | 1893050             
| Performance_schema_hosts_lost                 | 0                   
| Performance_schema_locker_lost                | 0                   
| Performance_schema_mutex_classes_lost         | 0                   
| Performance_schema_mutex_instances_lost       | 0                   
| Performance_schema_rwlock_classes_lost        | 0                   
| Performance_schema_rwlock_instances_lost      | 14905846            
| Performance_schema_session_connect_attrs_lost | 0                   
| Performance_schema_socket_classes_lost        | 0                   
| Performance_schema_socket_instances_lost      | 0                   
| Performance_schema_stage_classes_lost         | 0                   
| Performance_schema_statement_classes_lost     | 0                   
| Performance_schema_table_handles_lost         | 0                   
| Performance_schema_table_instances_lost       | 72450               
| Performance_schema_thread_classes_lost        | 0                   
| Performance_schema_thread_instances_lost      | 0                   
| Performance_schema_users_lost                 | 0                   
| Prepared_stmt_count                           | 4                   
| Qcache_free_blocks                            | 530                 
| Qcache_free_memory                            | 412104              
| Qcache_hits                                   | 43263242            
| Qcache_inserts                                | 11619205            
| Qcache_lowmem_prunes                          | 8809420             
| Qcache_not_cached                             | 526837              
| Qcache_queries_in_cache                       | 23516               
| Qcache_total_blocks                           | 72253               
| Queries                                       | 64820122            
| Questions                                     | 64490244            
| Rsa_public_key                                |                     
| Select_full_join                              | 112891              
| Select_full_range_join                        | 648                 
| Select_range                                  | 144436              
| Select_range_check                            | 20                  
| Select_scan                                   | 1417117             
| Slave_heartbeat_period                        | 1800.000            
| Slave_last_heartbeat                          |                     
| Slave_open_temp_tables                        | 0                   
| Slave_received_heartbeats                     | 0                   
| Slave_retried_transactions                    | 0                   
| Slave_running                                 | OFF                 
| Slow_launch_threads                           | 0                   
| Slow_queries                                  | 58                  
| Sort_merge_passes                             | 3382                
| Sort_range                                    | 1551341             
| Sort_rows                                     | 27351653            
| Sort_scan                                     | 2838100             
| Ssl_accept_renegotiates                       | 0                   
| Ssl_accepts                                   | 0                   
| Ssl_callback_cache_hits                       | 0                   
| Ssl_cipher                                    |                     
| Ssl_cipher_list                               |                     
| Ssl_client_connects                           | 0                   
| Ssl_connect_renegotiates                      | 0                   
| Ssl_ctx_verify_depth                          | 18446744073709551615
| Ssl_ctx_verify_mode                           | 5                   
| Ssl_default_timeout                           | 0                   
| Ssl_finished_accepts                          | 0                   
| Ssl_finished_connects                         | 0                   
| Ssl_server_not_after                          |                     
| Ssl_server_not_before                         |                     
| Ssl_session_cache_hits                        | 0                   
| Ssl_session_cache_misses                      | 0                   
| Ssl_session_cache_mode                        | SERVER              
| Ssl_session_cache_overflows                   | 0                   
| Ssl_session_cache_size                        | 128                 
| Ssl_session_cache_timeouts                    | 0                   
| Ssl_sessions_reused                           | 0                   
| Ssl_used_session_cache_entries                | 0                   
| Ssl_verify_depth                              | 0                   
| Ssl_verify_mode                               | 0                   
| Ssl_version                                   |                     
| Table_locks_immediate                         | 16649877            
| Table_locks_waited                            | 0                   
| Table_open_cache_hits                         | 16611281            
| Table_open_cache_misses                       | 503015              
| Table_open_cache_overflows                    | 492791              
| Tc_log_max_pages_used                         | 0                   
| Tc_log_page_size                              | 0                   
| Tc_log_page_waits                             | 0                   
| Threads_cached                                | 95                  
| Threads_connected                             | 9                   
| Threads_created                               | 196                 
| Threads_running                               | 2                   
| Uptime                                        | 128056              
| Uptime_since_flush_status                     | 128056
```

Comment: Did you noticed any problems? see also the slow query log if there are queries that take very long.

Comment: Open_table_definitions / Open_tables - I think you've hit the limit on these. Look at the Opened_*. These are much higher than those values. Maybe time to increase those unless for some reason you're flushing tables.

Comment: You "can't tune your way out of a performance problem" (usually).

Answer (score 0):

You may not have to change most in my.cnf as it is a part of the deal. Real devil s in the queries.

More CPU usage means costly queries and more processing

1. First check using **top** command if this is only during some regular backups, is standby configured in the same server.
2. Second enable **slow query log** and catch queries that needs tuning or
   missing indexes
3. Third Check the **EXPLAIN** plan of those queries and see total rows getting scanned and possible keys section
4. Lastly if none of the other works, **increase CPU cores**.

Comment: 4. Since one connection uses only one core, increasing cores is unlikely to help.  2. http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#slow_queries_and_slowlog

Answer (score 0):

In glancing over the VARIABLES and STATUS, I see

- The Query cache is not being efficient.  Either make use of DEMAND, or turn the QC off.
- A lot of temp tables; use the slowlog to find inefficient queries, and work on them.  (Suggest `long_query_time = 1`)
- `innodb_buffer_pool_size` can probably be larger.  Did you set it to a mere 2G, or did AWS set it for you?  (Do not raise it so much that swapping happens.)
- There are a lot of connections and a lot of open tables; maybe you should increase past 8GB of RAM.